# Employment in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working, employment, job-hunting

I recently visited UK and I like it there. I am thinking of moving, working there, hopefully for good. Does anyone here know any company who are looking for Sales people in FMCG industry who are willing to sponsor so I can apply? Or any options so I can apply for a job. Hope to get response. Thanks!

Comment: What is FMCG industry?

Comment: Seems to be Fast Moving Consumer Goods, such as packaged food.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are not an EU citizen. The UK has a list of occupations where there is a shortage of skilled workers. Approved companies can sponsor visas for skilled workers if they cannot fill a vacancy within the EU labour market. It is unlikely that your skill set as given meets the criteria. Do you have any qualifications on this list: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-k-shortage-occupation-list ?